# Firefox extension to redirect files

Tags: firefox, redirect, firefox-addon

I want an extension which redirects all requests for:

`http://website.com/foo.js`

to:

`http://localhost/myfoo.js`

I cannot use the hosts file to edit the host from website.com to localhost because I only want the redirect to apply to foo.js.

I tried using this extension:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirector/

But it only works if you type `http://website.com/foo.js` in the address bar, I want it to redirect anything that wants to access this link to my localhost version.

For example, if `http://website.com/bar.html` uses `http://website.com/foo.js` then I want it to use `http://localhost/myfoo.js` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [`request-redirect`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request-redirect) module, and this code:

```
let { Redirect } = require("request-redirect");
Redirect({ from: "http://website.com/foo.js", to: "http://localhost/myfoo.js" });
```

For more information on getting started with building an add-on [see this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29).

Comment: Is there no existing add-on for this basic functionality? I'm shocked.